googlesheet get last non blank row from specific rows
By Following code in google spreadsheet I select last not empty row (based on data in H column and get data from cell "O").
=INDEX(O:O,MAX(IF( H:H<>"",ROW(H:H),0)))

It work properly. Now, I want to add condition to that search so it check only specific rows. ( Rows with specific amount in A column, so I need to add A:A="string" condition to that formula) how can I do that?


You may try:
=index(O:O,max(if((H:H<>"")*(A:A="String"),row(H:H),0)))

OR
=chooserows(filter(O:O,H:H<>"",A:A="String"),-1)


both work nice, thanks

Now how can I have SUM for several amount in A:A groups. I mean I have A1:A10="String1" , A20:A16="String2" , A25:A32="String3" and son on. @rockinfreakshow

Now how can I have... dpfarhad, why wasn't this included in the original question? No doubt @rockinfreakshow can supply an answer but I think this should be posted as a new question rather than trying to add a supplementary question by way of a comment.
